# Eloquent accessing related data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

I'm trying to get relations from data returned.

in User

```
public function folders()
{
  return $this->hasMany("App\Folder");
}

public function rootFolder()
{
  return $this->folders()->where("parentid", null);
}
```

in Folder

```
public function subFolders() {
  return $this->hasMany("App\Folder", "parentid");
}

public function parentFolder()
{
  return $this->belongsTo("App\Folder", "parentid");
}
```

in Controller

```
$root = auth()->user()->rootFolder;
$subs = $root->subFolders;
foreach ($subs as $sub) {
    echo $sub->name;
}
```

I'm getting

```
Property [subFolders] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

However if

```
$root = new Folder;
```

Exception disappears.

Do I have to somehow tell the return data from rootFolder function that you are a Folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function returns a query:

```
public function rootFolder()
{
  return $this->folders()->where("parentid", null);
}
```

So this one is trying to access the "subFolders" attribute of a query:

```
$root = auth()->user()->rootFolder;
$subs = $root->subFolders;
```

This change would work to return a Folder object:

```
public function rootFolder()
{
  return $this->folders()->where("parentid", null)->first();
}
```